# gnuplot: default value for heatmap (if no data is available)

Tags: graph, 3d, gnuplot, heatmap, default-value

Can you tell me how to specify the default cb (or z) value?

I build a 3d chart {x,y,z} or {x,y,cb}, but for different x there are different ranges of y, and as a result white bars are visible on the chart (for heatmap/colorbox). I would like to see no white stripes, and where there is no data, gnuplot would substitute the default value (for example, 0) and, accordingly, paint the field with the appropriate color for heatmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, depending on exactly what plot mode you are using and what type of data you have.  In general you can use two properties of the color assignment to get what you want:

1) out-of-bound values are mapped to the color of the extreme min or max of the colorbar. So one option is to assign a palette that has your desired "default" color at the min and max, independent of whatever palette function you use for the rest of the range

2) data values that are "missing" or "not-a-number" generally leave a hole in the grid of a pixel image or heat map that lets the background color show through.

There is a demo `imageNaN.dem` in the standard demo set that shows use of these features for several 2D and 3D heat map commands.  The output from a heatmap generated by `splot $matrixdata matrix with image` is shown below.You can see extreme values pinned to the min/max of the colorbar range.

Note that if you want some color other than the backgroundn to show through, you could position a colored rectangle behind the heat map surface.

```
# Define the test data as a named data block
$matrixdata << EOD
0    5 4 3  0
?    2 2 0  1
Junk 1 2 3  5
NaN  0 0 3  0
Inf  3 2 0  3
-Inf 0 1 2  3
EOD

set view map
set datafile missing '?'
unset xtics
set ytics   ("0" 0.0, "?" 1.0, "Junk" 2.0, "NaN" 3.0, "Inf" 4.0, "-Inf" 5.0)

set cblabel "Score" 
set cbrange [ -2.0 : 7.0 ]

splot $matrixdata matrix using 1:2:(0):3 with image
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Ethan, I really don't have some data, which results in white slits.

I can fill in the missing data 0 at the stage of forming the data file, but then some files become very large and gnuplot spends all the memory.

So I'm looking for a way to solve the problem.

My example:

[image]

For @Ethan: my code:

```
            set arrow from 0,86400 rto graph 1, graph 0 nohead ls 5 front

#===> decision of problem
            set object rectangle from graph 0, graph 0 to graph 1, graph 1 behind fc rgbcolor 'blue' fs noborder

            set pm3d map
#           set pm3d interpolate 32,32
            set size square
            set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31

            splot inputFullPath u 2:1:(percentage($4)) notitle
```

and my data (for example):

```
0 1 0.1
0 2 0.2
0 4 0.5
# -------- {0,5..7} - white gap

# -------- {1,1..3} - white gap
1 3 0.6
1 4 0.5
1 7 0.9
```

Comment: Please clarify by showing the commands you are using to generate the plot and a sample of the input data.   I am guessing that  the white space to the left and right of each horizontal colored line is background color showing through from "not-a-number' data values as I described previously. You could change it to some other color by adding a rectangle behind the plot: `set object rectange from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fillstyle solid fillcolor "gray"`.   The horizontal white dashed line looks like an artifact from an extraneous grid or contour setting.

Comment: @Ethan, yes, find decision `set object rectangle from graph 0, graph 0 to graph 1, graph 1 behind fc rgbcolor 'blue' fs noborder`

Comment: @Ethan - Setting the background is an obvious and simple solution to my problem, but there are a few drawbacks to this method: 1) if I change the colorbox palette, I will have to manually change the background color myself 2) still the background color is not the default value for colorbox when there are no points, i.e. another object is added to the graph

Comment: 1) You can set the rectangle color to match the lowest colorbar value automatically: `set obj 1 fillcolor palette fraction 0`. 2) I do not understand what you mean by "default color". If there are no points there is nothing to color, right?  What exactly is supposed to use this default color?

Comment: @Ethan, big thanks
2) - I just don't want to have ugly white gap if there is no data - it means that these points have minimal or zero values (just because otherwise the file size will be huge)